# Get nth and mth elements of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

A very basic question but I cannot find similar question in here og by googling.

```
tmp = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

I can extract 2 by `tmp[1]` and 2 to 4 by `tmp[1:4]`

Suppose I want to extract 2 AND 4. What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: with `tmp[[1,3]]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.take()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html)

```
import numpy as np
tmp = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]).take([1,4])
# Out[4]: (2, 5)
```